# Scraping view function remembers its previous iterations

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have the following view function used to scrape data:

```
def results(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RoomForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form_city = form.cleaned_data['city'].title()
            form_country = form.cleaned_data['country'].title()
            form_arrival_date = form.cleaned_data['arrival_date']
            form_departure_date = form.cleaned_data['departure_date']
            form_pages_to_scrape = form.cleaned_data['pages_to_scrape']

    #launch scraper   
    scraper = AIRBNB_scraper(city=form_city, country=form_country, arrival_date=str(form_arrival_date), departure_date=str(form_departure_date))
    scraped_dataframe = scraper.scrape_multiple_pages(last_page_selector_number=form_pages_to_scrape)
    scraped_dataframe_sorted = scraped_dataframe.sort_values('prices')
    print(scraped_dataframe_sorted)

    #convert scraped dataframe into lists
    prices = scraped_dataframe_sorted['prices'].tolist()
    listings_links = scraped_dataframe_sorted['listings_links'].tolist()
    listings_names = scraped_dataframe_sorted['listings_names'].tolist()
    photo_links = scraped_dataframe_sorted['photo_links'].tolist()

    dictionary = zip(prices, listings_links, listings_names, photo_links)

    context = {'dictionary': dictionary}
    return render(request, 'javascript/results.html', context)
```

On form submit, a post request is sent to this function using AJAX:

```
var frm = $('#login-form');
frm.submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/results",
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#table").html(data);
            $('#go_back').remove();
        },
        error: function(data) {
            $("#table").html("Something went wrong!");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

After that the scraped data is displayed as HTML table on the same page the form is on.

The problem is the number of scraped items doubles every time the form submit is done. So for example if the number of scraped items on first button click is sixteen, the output will be 16, but on the second run it will be 32, then 64, and so on.

It is like the app remembers previous form submits, but I don't see any reason why. I tried clearin - at the end of this function - the pandas dataframe used to store the scraped data and also the dictionary passed as context, but to no avail.

The form is:

```
class RoomForm(forms.Form):
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    arrival_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker'
                                }), required=False)
    departure_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker'
                                }), required=False)
    pages_to_scrape = forms.IntegerField(label='Pages to scrape (max. 17)', min_value=0, max_value=17, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style':'width: 188px'}))
```

AIRBNB_scraper is:

```
import requests, bs4
import re
import pandas as pd

price_pattern = re.compile(r'\d*\s*?,?\s*?\d*\szł')
photo_link_pattern = re.compile(r'https.*\)')

prices = []
listings_links = []
photo_links = []
listings_names = []

class AIRBNB_scraper():

    def __init__(self, city, country, accomodation_type='homes', arrival_date='2018-03-25', departure_date='2018-04-10'):
        self.city = city
        self.country = country
        self.arrival_date = arrival_date
        self.departure_date = departure_date
        self.accomodation_type = accomodation_type

    def make_soup(self, page_number):
        url = 'https://www.airbnb.pl/s/'+ self.city +'--'+ self.country +'/'+ self.accomodation_type  +'?query='+ self.city +'%2C%20'+ self.country +'&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2F'+ self.accomodation_type  +'&checkin=' + self.arrival_date + '&checkout=' + self.departure_date + '&section_offset=' + str(page_number)
        response = requests.get(url)  
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

        return soup

    def get_listings(self, page_number):

        soup = self.make_soup(page_number)
        listings = soup.select('._f21qs6')
        number_of_listings = len(listings)
        print('\n' + "Number of listings found: " + str(number_of_listings))

        while number_of_listings != 18:
            print('\n' + str(number_of_listings) + ' is not correct number of listings, it should be 18. Trying again now.')
            soup = self.make_soup(page_number)
            listings = soup.find_all('div', class_='_f21qs6')
            number_of_listings = len(listings)

        print('\n' + "All fine! The number of listings is: " + str(number_of_listings) + '. Starting scraping now')

        return listings

    def scrape_listings_per_page(self, page_number):

        listings_to_scrape = self.get_listings(page_number)

        for listing in listings_to_scrape:

            #get price
            price_container = listing.find_all('span', class_='_hylizj6')
            price_search = re.search(price_pattern, str(price_container))
            price = price_search.group()

            #get listing_link
            listing_link = 'https://www.airbnb.pl' + listing.find('a', class_='_15ns6vh')['href']

            #get photo_link
            photo_link_node = listing.find('div', class_="_1df8dftk")['style']
            photo_link_search = re.search(photo_link_pattern, str(photo_link_node))
            #~ if photo_link_search:
                #~ print('Is regex match')
            #~ else:
                #~ print('No regex match')
            photo_link_before_strip = photo_link_search.group()
            photo_link = photo_link_before_strip[:-1] #remove ") at the end of link 

            #get listing_name
            listing_name = listing.find('div', class_='_1rths372').text

            #append lists
            prices.append(price)
            listings_links.append(listing_link)
            photo_links.append(photo_link)
            listings_names.append(listing_name)

    def scrape_multiple_pages(self, last_page_selector_number):

        last_page_selector_number += 1
        for x in range(0, last_page_selector_number):#18
            self.scrape_listings_per_page(x)
            print('\n' + "INDEX OF PAGE BEING SCRAPED: " + str(x))
            scraped_data = pd.DataFrame({'prices': prices,
                                        'listings_links': listings_links,
                                        'photo_links': photo_links,
                                        'listings_names': listings_names})
        return scraped_data
```

Comment: What is "render" and what is it doing? "return render(request, 'javascript/results.html', context)"

Comment: Please show the code for AIRBNB_scraper and RoomForm.

Comment: @Daniel, I have added the code for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have module-level variables: `prices`, `listings_links`, etc. You append to these inside your AIRBNB_scraper instance but they are not part of that instance, and will persist between calls. You should make them instance attributes - define them as `self.prices` etc in the `__init__` method.